# Can I upload a new version of my app changing "public" value in firebase.json?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I re-design a SPA that is deployed in firebase with custom domain, I have done all my test on another firebase project, now I would like to deploy the new version to the public app by creating a new folder, lets say public2 in the public project, change the entry in `firebase.json` and then do a new  `firebase deploy.`

Can this be done? and in case I will like to return to prior version, be able to change it back ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was straight forward, just copied the code of the new site to a new folder and changed the firebase.json entry to referring this new folder.

then issue `firebase deploy` again.

Hope this helps someone else.